# how to connect navicat to mysql on aws EC2?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, navicat

When I tried to use **navicat** to connect **mysql** on **AWS**, it always reject the connection.
I'm sure my IP address is correct and the port is correct as I checked on **EC2** for several times. Also the username and password are correct too because I can log in **mysql** on **EC2**.
I don't know what is wrong here. Any help would be really appreciated.

[image: error info]
[image]

Comment: Maybe your user in mysql is only declared as user@localhost? Or Port 3306 is not open on EC2?

Comment: Does Navicat run locally or in EC2? If it runs locally, do you have a public IP? Is the port 3306 open in the security group?

Comment: I have solved this by adding a new user and granting all the privileges to it. THX!

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that will validate is that your instance of aws has active the port to which you want to connect in this case 3306 if it does not work with this you can connect by means of a SSH of the following way remembering that it has to have active the port 22:

1. Configure the ssh option

**host:** add the one that EC2 gives you e.g. ec2-127-0-0-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
**Port:** 22.
**user:** ubuntu or root (or the one indicated in your aws configuration).
**Authentication Method:** public key.
**Private key:** your .pem

2. In general:

**Connection Name:** whatever you want
**Host:** localhost or 127.0.0.1
**Port:** 3306
**User:** the database user
**Pass:** the database user.